# Python Loop Only Returns First Group That Meets Condition (Data, code, picture, and examples provided)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, if-statement

## Why does the loop think that only one group meets the condition (if NaN present in group values)?

#### There are several NaNs throughout the other groups, but it only returns the first group.

- It appears to iterate over each group, but does not properly return the others that have NaN values.
- Goal is to return the groups that have `nan` values...

DataFrame:

```
sample_data = [['USA', 'gdp', 2001, 10],['USA', 'avgIQ', 2001, 100],['USA', 'people', 2001, 1000],['USA', 'dragons', 2001, 3],['CHN', 'gdp', 2001, 12], ['CHN', 'avgIQ', 2001, 120],['CHN', 'people', 2001, 2000],['CHN', 'dragons', 2001, 1],['RUS', 'gdp', 2001, 11],['RUS', 'avgIQ', 2001, 105], ['RUS', 'people', 2001, 1500],['RUS', 'dragons', 2001, np.nan],['USA', 'gdp', 2002, 12],['USA', 'avgIQ', 2002, 105],['USA', 'people', 2002, 1200], ['USA', 'dragons', 2002, np.nan],['CHN', 'gdp', 2002, 14],['CHN', 'avgIQ', 2002, 127],['CHN', 'people', 2002, 3100],['CHN', 'dragons', 2002, 4], ['RUS', 'gdp', 2002, 11],['RUS', 'avgIQ', 2002, 99],['RUS', 'people', 2002, 1600],['RUS', 'dragons', 2002, np.nan],['USA', 'gdp', 2003, 15], ['USA', 'avgIQ', 2003, 115],['USA', 'people', 2003, 2000],['USA', 'dragons', 2003, np.nan],['CHN', 'gdp', 2003, 16],['CHN', 'avgIQ', 2003, 132], ['CHN', 'people', 2003, 4000],['CHN', 'dragons', 2003, 6],['RUS', 'gdp', 2003, 11],['RUS', 'avgIQ', 2003, 108],['RUS', 'people', 2003, 2000], ['RUS', 'dragons', 2003, np.nan],['USA', 'gdp', 2004, 18],['USA', 'avgIQ', 2004, 111],['USA', 'people', 2004, 2500],['USA', 'dragons', 2004, np.nan], ['CHN', 'gdp', 2004, 18],['CHN', 'avgIQ', 2004, 140],['CHN', 'people', 2004, np.nan],['CHN', 'dragons', 2004, np.nan], ['RUS', 'gdp', 2004, 15],['RUS', 'avgIQ', 2004, 103],['RUS', 'people', 2004, 2800],['RUS', 'dragons', 2004, np.nan], ['USA', 'gdp', 2005, 23],['USA', 'avgIQ', 2005, 111],['USA', 'people', 2005, 3700],['USA', 'dragons', 2005, 8],['CHN', 'gdp', 2005, 22], ['CHN', 'avgIQ', 2005, 143],['CHN', 'people', 2005, 6000],['CHN', 'dragons', 2005, 15],['RUS', 'gdp', 2005, 17],['RUS', 'avgIQ', 2005, np.nan], ['RUS', 'people', 2005, 3000],['RUS', 'dragons', 2005, np.nan]]

sample_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data, columns = ['A','B','C','D'])

sample_df['C'] = sample_df['C'].astype(float) 
sample_df.head()
```

[image]

```
Data columns (total 4 columns):
A    60 non-null object
B    60 non-null object
C    60 non-null float64
D    49 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(2)
```

> ### The following Loop is the problem. It runs through all the groups, but only properly returns the first group to meet the criteria in the if-statement.
>
> #### Note the hashtags I placed in the output.

```
sample_group = sample_df.groupby(['A', 'B'])

for group_index, group in sample_group:

    if group.isnull().values.any() in group.values:
        print(group)

    else:
        #continue
        print('Checked group but could not satisfy condition', group_index)
```

```
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('CHN', 'avgIQ')
      A        B        C     D
7   CHN  dragons 2,001.00  1.00
19  CHN  dragons 2,002.00  4.00
31  CHN  dragons 2,003.00  6.00
43  CHN  dragons 2,004.00   nan   #prints the group because it does in fact have an nan value
55  CHN  dragons 2,005.00 15.00
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('CHN', 'gdp')
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('CHN', 'people')   #this has nan values
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('RUS', 'avgIQ')
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('RUS', 'dragons')  #this has nan values
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('RUS', 'gdp')
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('RUS', 'people')  
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('USA', 'avgIQ')    #this has nan values
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('USA', 'dragons')
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('USA', 'gdp')
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('USA', 'people')
```

#### Whereas the following works just fine:

- in this case, the loop looks for groups that have a value of 12 somewhere in them, and there are only two groups that meet this criteria, so it works great.

```
for group_index, group in sample_group:

    if 12 in group.values:
        print(group)

    else:
        #continue
        print('Checked group but could not satisfy condition', group_index)
```

```
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('CHN', 'avgIQ')
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('CHN', 'dragons')
      A    B        C     D
4   CHN  gdp 2,001.00 12.00   #Has a 12
16  CHN  gdp 2,002.00 14.00
28  CHN  gdp 2,003.00 16.00
40  CHN  gdp 2,004.00 18.00
52  CHN  gdp 2,005.00 22.00
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('CHN', 'people')
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('RUS', 'avgIQ')
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('RUS', 'dragons')
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('RUS', 'gdp')
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('RUS', 'people')
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('USA', 'avgIQ')
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('USA', 'dragons')
      A    B        C     D
0   USA  gdp 2,001.00 10.00
12  USA  gdp 2,002.00 12.00   #Has a 12
24  USA  gdp 2,003.00 15.00
36  USA  gdp 2,004.00 18.00
48  USA  gdp 2,005.00 23.00
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('USA', 'people')
```

The first loop clearly goes over each group, but only prints the first one that meets the if-statement criteria.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to when you say group. Are you looking for the rows with nan values in it? If so, why not make use of pandas indexing? Something like `sample_df[pd.isnull(sample_df).any(axis=1)]` should work. The point of using pandas is that you don't have to loop through the data to find conditions.

Comment: @JoeHabel by group I mean each group in the groupby. More specifically, each unique pairing of country and feature. I use the groupby and loop over the groups because the end goal is to use Impyuter's `mice` on the groups with nan values, then I plan to put the imputed values back into the original df (but this will be a later step). Reason I do it this way is so that the imputation does not get confused when trying to create values for the nans (as CHN  avgIQ is much higher, an imputation based on features across all years and countries, would be less accurate). 1/2

Comment: This method organizes each country_feature pairing, and then imputes missing values using information ONLY within that particular country_feature group. This is way the imputation takes advantage of the time series ['C']  (I know it is in `float` now, but that is because `mice` needs float inputs) and keeps the resulting values more accurate. 2/2

Comment: Please share code/data as text in the post itself, not as images. Also, don’t use `.values`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change

`if group.isnull().values.any() in group.values:`

to

`if group.isnull().values.any():`

it works

Comment: Good lord, thank you!! I wonder why the `in group.values:` was messing it up... I had tried `if group.isnull().values.any() == True in group.values:` before but it did not work. Thank you again!